# UIScrollView doesn't work first time but works fine second... Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, uiscrollview

I am using a UIScrollView to show a larger amount of text and images. I haven't done any bigger changes in setting, i build everthing in interface builder (Xcode 4). I have set the content insets to 1370 on botton, because of my view.

The problem is when I start the application and I go to the view with a scrollView, nothing appear in the scrollView, but if I go back and then go to the view with a scrollView again then it appear as I want... :/

If I don't set the content insets, it works great BUT then it doesn't scroll down so it only show what fits inside the view.

Is it any smarter way to combine large amount of text and images?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post some code. It seems like it might have something to do with your ViewDidLoad function, but it's really hard to fix it without knowing exactly what you're doing.

Comment: I don't have any code almost, I have done it directly in the design.

My app is a view based application where I just switch views when I change pages. And in one of the pages I have a scrollview to view information (text and images). The only thing i call, is to view that view, because I already done the design with text and image in the designmode. I have one textView and two imageview in the scrollview. And haven't wrote any code for the scrollview, the only setting is that I have set the content insets to 1370 on botton, because of my view. Otherwise it won't scroll, but then it work fine.

Comment: And I can't use ViewDidLoad function? :/ because it won't call this function when i have View based application...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that whenever you are moving to next i.e on scrollView at that time does your array have the data?  Just cross check it.

Comment: I don't have any code almost, I have done it directly in the design.

My app is a view based application where I just switch views when I change pages. And in one of the pages I have a scrollview to view information (text and images). The only thing i call, is to view that view, because I already done the design with text and image in the designmode. I have one textView and two imageview in the scrollview. And haven't wrote any code for the scrollview, the only setting is that I have set the content insets to 1370 on botton, because of my view. Otherwise it won't scroll, but then it work fine.